# Анимация крутящегося бордера

Tags: html, css

Как сделать при нажатии кнопки, чтобы бордер крутился по кругу. Чтобы крутился вроде прелоадера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пока бордер у изображения такой

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-radius:50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
     opacity: 1;
}  

img:hover {    
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition:0.6s;  
}
```

Comment: В вопросе многое зависит от того, какой border. Одноцветную окружность как ни крути, видимого эффекта не будет.

Comment: а нет эффекта просто градиентного бордера?просто для имейдж при псевдоклассе active?только чтобы он еще и крутился при горизонтали

Answer (score 12):

Из примера логика думаю понятна....

```css
#imgwrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}

#border {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  border-top-color: green;
  border-left-color: yellow;
  border-right-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#imgwrap:active img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.6s;
}

#imgwrap:active #border {
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(360deg);
  transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgwrap">
  <img src="https://million-wallpapers.ru/wallpapers/0/46/437032157963702.jpg" />
  <div id="border"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

На `css` закругленная градиентная граница не получится. Можно вот такими костылями. Или смотреть в сторону `svg`

```css
.circle{
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:3px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
   position:relative;
}
.circle:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:linear-gradient(green,blue,black);
}
.circle img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:inherit;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.circle:active:before{
  animation:rotate .3s linear infinite;
  transform-origin:center;
}
@keyframes rotate{
  from{
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Нажать</p>
<a href="#" class="circle">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Flag_of_Switzerland_%28Pantone%29.svg/250px-Flag_of_Switzerland_%28Pantone%29.svg.png" />
</a>
```